# how to apply click event listener to image in android

Tags: android

i want to apply an onClickListener event to an imageView, how do I accomplish this? Can anyone provide me with some source code examples

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})
 - The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, 
  int)

Comment: @Jaseem: Looks like you have `imports` that make your compiler interpret `OnClickListener` as a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`. Try explicitly specifying `(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });`

Comment: I think the solution just below is better. Setting `android:onClick="imageClick" ` in the XML seems easier to understand. The above LIKE solution works brilliant in web and JavaScript. Seems like Java is trying to copy JavaScript. It will never be that good.

Comment: @Jaseem, it seems you are not following the question properly, as XML may not be in use for the question. As they specified "in code", this answer is best. Also, you should learn more about javascript and java and learn why this code is very different to closures...

Comment: @DavidHedlund shouldn't you `@Override` the method?

Comment: @ArtemIce: Ah, correct. I omitted that part in my code. While it isn't required, it's a best practice you want to stick to, so good point.

Comment: @DavidHedlund, maybe it's better to include android:clickable="true" for clarity.

Answer (score 29):

In xml:

```
<ImageView  
 android:clickable="true"  
 android:onClick="imageClick"  
 android:src="@drawable/myImage">  
 </ImageView>
```

In code

```
 public class Test extends Activity {  
  ........  
  ........  
 public void imageClick(View view) {  
  //Implement image click function  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example.

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<GridView
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:background="#fff7ff"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
```

grid_single.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textColor="#3a0fff">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomGrid.java:

```
package com.example.lalit.gridtest;

import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] web;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public CustomGrid(Context c, String[] web, int[] Imageid) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(web[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.lalit.gridtest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GridView grid;
    String[] web = {
            "Mom",
            "Mahendra",
            "Narayan",
            "Bhai",
            "Deepak",
            "Sanjay",
            "Navdeep",
            "Lovesh",


    };
    int[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id){

                if (web[position].toString().equals("Mom")) {
                    try {
                        String uri ="te:"+ "**********";

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }


                    if (web[position].toString().equals("Mahendra")) {
                        try {
                            String uri = "tel:" + "**********";

                            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                            startActivity(callIntent);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }


                      if(web[position].toString().equals("Narayan")){

                    try {
                        String uri = "tel:" + "**********";

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


             }
                if(web[position].toString().equals("Bhai")){

                    try {
                        String uri = "tel:" + "**********";

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


                }

                if(web[position].toString().equals("Deepak")){

                    try {
                        String uri = "tel:" + "**********";

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


                }


                if(web[position].toString().equals("Sanjay")){

                    try {
                        String uri = "tel:" + "**********";

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


                }
                if(web[position].toString().equals("Navdeep")){

                    try {
                        String uri = "tel:" + "**********";

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


                }
                if(web[position].toString().equals("Lovesh")){

                    try {
                        String uri = "tel:" + "**********";

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


                }

                }



        });

    }

    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lalit.gridtest" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lambda Expression JAVA**

```
ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

img.setOnClickListener(v -> 
{
    //Your Handler Code
});
```