# Stop running for loop until I get a response from my onClickListener

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have a for loop, but I need it to stop doing anything until I get a response from the user (aka the user selects left or right). I'm doing this in Android, but I'm not sure of the best way to go about this. The "left" and "right" are images. So I'm listening for left or right to be hit before I keep moving on. I need the loop to go on about 50 times. This is what I have so far.

```
int testlength = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < testlength; i++) {
    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.left);
    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);

    //Stop the for loop and get the input from the user     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop.

Just exit the routine once you have 50 responses:

```
int count = 0;

String[] responses = new String[50];

left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        left.setImageResource(R.drawable.left);
        right.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);

        responses[count] = "Left";

        count++;

        if(count == 50)
        {
            // Exit the activity
        }
    }
};

right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        left.setImageResource(R.drawable.left);
        right.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);

        responses[count] = "Right";

        count++;

        if(count == 50)
        {
            // Exit the activity
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution in my opinion would be to use semaphores:

```
class Example {
     private Semaphore sem;

     public Example() {
         sem = new Semaphore(0);
     }

     public void onClick(...) {
          // Do stuff
          sem.release();
     }

     public void myLoop() {
         int testlength = 50;
         for (int i = 0; i < testlength; i++) {
             left.setImageResource(R.drawable.left);
             right.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);

             sem.acquire();
         }
     }
}
```

Remember that this assumes that myLoop isn't running on the UI thread.

Comment: Hmm... people agree with you, but I'm going to have to read up on semaphores. I appreciate the answer.

Comment: Semaphores are a relatively simple concept. They are like mutex locks, however they are countable. So when you release a semaphore you increment its internal counter, and when you acquire a semaphore you decrement the counter. The magic happens when you try to acquire the semaphore and the counter is zero. In this case the acquiring thread will block and wait until another thread releases the semaphore. That way, the counter is never less than zero, and when it is zero, it guarantees that any other thread that tries to acquire it only continues after another thread has incremented the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this -

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId); 
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
       // your code here 
    } 
});
```

That is, you want to use an event rather than loop waiting for someone to click. Tight loops are generally a nasty idea.

I got the code from this thread - [how to apply click event listener to image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839273/how-to-apply-click-event-to-image-in-android)

Comment: Why do you want to run it 50 times? I assumed you were just using the loop to await the click

Comment: Ok, I understand a bit better now, though it seems a strange thing. So you want the user to tap the screen 50 times? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want the left and right images to appear. and then get the response. store the response. and then let the user select left or right again. store the response... etc

Comment: And you want this to happen exactly 50 times?

Comment: Well, it's a variable. So I should be able to change it from one to a million.