# How to save image in an array android after get response from server?

Tags: android

In android I want to store images in an array after getting response from server. For example hitting a web service in response we get 10 images. How to store in an array and how to change each image every 10 seconds. Any help would be appreciated here and please provide sample code if you can so?

Comment: probably you should Google first.I think there're many examples out there

Comment: Yes I did, didn't find any reliable solution so that ???

Comment: Can you explain? I don't understand..

Comment: For example if you have a web service and you hit that service from post and in response you get 10 images, how you save that responded images in an array??