# onClickListener() misses sometimes for ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am simply using a **PNG** image as source in `ImageView` & want to add a `onClickListener()`. Problem is that button's `onClick()` doesn't trigger smoothly, means when I click on image sometimes it works fine & sometimes it doesn't work. Even I have added some padding around ImageView to increase the clickable area. I also tried replacing `ImageView` with `ImageButton` but no luck. That is also behaving same way.
Here is my code:

```
ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
   public void onClick(final View v) 
   {
     finish() 
   } 
});
```

XML for button:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/back"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:padding="10dp"
android:src="@drawable/btn_back"/>
```

Please note that I am using this `ImageView` in a custom action bar.

Comment: try adding `clickable` attribute to `true` in the xml file

Comment: First thing is that you have already applied fixed height and width still you have applied _android:padding="10dp"_ which decrease the size of image. Instead of use different dimensions icons with _wrap_content_ and then apply padding to image view so can get more area for that icon.

Comment: As its height and width is very low. just try adding padding in it and make height and width more, Hope it will work fine

Comment: Tried with wrap_content, but no luck.

Comment: Share your full layout maybe another component disturbing it.

Comment: [This question is already answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1839454/11856637)

Comment: @Shivam please look into my question, that is not similar one. I am already using the procedure that is explained in referred question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Size of Image is so small
2. You can use Toolbar instead of custom action bar. You can call: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: Though not explained in detail, but using Toolbar is the right option. Which is referred in this answer. That's why accepted this. And image size is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

Already your image size is too low, `24dp` along with that you're giving extra padding to it `10dp` which results in a smaller image hence the click is not obtaining correctly.
Try removing the padding and use `margin` if possible

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_back"/>
```

Or you can add a container layout which can wrap around the `ImageView`` and give click listener to that.

Answer (score 0):

without code it's will impossible to find your problem , because it's not happens in any case, you can check by remove padding otherwise,I'm not seeing any problem in this xml

Comment: whta's the size of your image, is it vector image or you take it from google

Comment: OP knows it. I m not!

Comment: i think the problem with your image,see i have done the same thing and it works.. you can check where have you done the mistake...share the answer with you,

Answer (score 0):

**XML layout**

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />
```

**here is class**

```
public class About_us extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView back;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);

        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(final View v)
            {
                finish();
            }
        });  }

}
```

Comment: Also don't post another answer just edit your first answer.